# How to deeplink to a fragment id that is generated by angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pseudo-class, deep-linking

I'd like to deeplink to an HTML fragment id that is generated by ng-repeat on the target page. E.g. the link could look like this: http://www.example.com/list#item-12345

The problem is that the fragment is not available at the time the page loads (it is generated by ng-repeat), so the browser cannot position the window to the element, nor can add the :target pseudo class to the element. When the ng-repeat processes the data, this positioning & css pseudo class addition is not performed.

Is there an elegant solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Would `$anchorScroll` as described [here](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html) do? (and [specs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll))

Comment: Thanks! I try to wrap my head around this, although I'd prefer something more simple as I don't use routes, and would prefer to keep my urls clean.

Comment: In the link above, the author is using it with *and* without routes, check it out. It still needs to change the hash of the URL though...